# Weibel's book exercise 1.1.2. Cycles get sent to cycles by chain complex homs $u : C_{\cdot} \to D_{\cdot}$

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

A morphism of chain complexes is a family of homs $u_n : C_n \to D_n $ such that $u_{n-1} d_n^{(C)} = d_n^{(D)} u_n$.  Weibel's book says that cycles "get sent to cycles".  To me that means that $u_n(Z_n^{(C)}) = Z_n^{(D)}$.  I can show that lhs $\subset$ rhs easily: $x \in Z_n = \ker d_n^{(C)}$ means that lhs $= 0$ ($0$'s always map to $0$) and so $u_n(x) \in \ker d_n^{(D)}$ by the commuting formula.  However, I can't show that if $y \in \ker d_n^{(D)}$ then there is a pre-image of $y$ in $\ker d_n^{(C)}$.  So does she mean that $u$ maps cycles in $C$ *into* cycles in $D$ but not necessarily surjectively?  *Confused*

Thanks!

Comment: "Cycles get sent to cycles" means $u_n(Z_n^{(C)}) \subset Z_n^{(D)}$, the image of a cycle is a cycle. Not that all cycles in $D$ are images of cycles in $C$. The latter would mean that inclusion of chain complexes is generally not a morphism. That would be odd and inconvenient.

Comment: Thanks dude!!!!.  I'll proceed with the exercise now with more confidence.